# Most basic Angular demo not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm following an online tutorial, and it says all I need is angularJs script, and a ng-app tag.

Following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBhqLRoRDgo

So I tried it, but ... it seems the most basic part, I'm failing at:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aX8C3MTPh2fu3klt54Qk?p=preview

```
{{ 843 / 42 }}
```

That should show the answer, as opposed to showing a string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, if I select an Angula version 1.x, it works. It seems 2.x, something has changed, and the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have coded in angular 1 version but you have added angular 2 scripts. In simplest case you can add prior version or write in 2 fashion.

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

In your plunker code, it seems you are using angular 2 that needs more preparations, (see angular 2 [quickstart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)).

replace the script tag with this one:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the URL given in the script src is a 404.  Also, you're using angular 1.x syntax in your code.

For coding in angular 2.x, you should have a look at this quick start: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart